# js getTimezoneOffset() in php

Tags: php, javascript, timezone

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*(-1);
```

This JS function returns the UTC Time Zone of the machine in minutes. Is there any PHP function does the same thing?
Thank you..

Comment: For the webserver machine or for the client user's machine?

Comment: For client's pc, where the site is browsing from...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php // RAY_easy_client_time.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);


// USE JAVASCRIPT TO GET THE CLIENT TIME AND COMPUTE THE OFFSET FROM THE SERVER TIME


// LOCATION OF THE SERVER - COULD BE ANYWHERE
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');

// DIFFERENCE OF SERVER TIME FROM UTC
$server_offset_seconds = date('Z');

// WHEN THE FORM IS SUBMITTED
if (!empty($_POST))
{
    // JAVASCRIPT TELLS US THE CLIENT TIME OFFSET FROM GMT / UTC
    $client_offset_minutes = $_POST["date_O"];
    $client_offset_seconds = $client_offset_minutes * 60;

    // THE TIME WE WANT AT THE CLIENT LOCATION
    $client_timestring = 'TODAY 7:00AM';

    // MAKE THE COMPUTATIONS, INCORPORATING THE OFFSET FROM GMT
    $client_timestamp  = strtotime($client_timestring) + $client_offset_seconds;
    $server_timestamp  = $client_timestamp + $server_offset_seconds;
    $server_timestring = date('l, F j, Y \a\t g:i a', $server_timestamp);

    echo "<br/>ACCORDING TO THE VALUE FROM PHP date Z";
    echo "<br/>SERVER IS LOCATED $server_offset_seconds SECONDS FROM UTC";
    echo "<br/>";

    echo "<br/>ACCORDING TO THE VALUE FROM JS dateObject.getTimezoneOffset()";
    echo "<br/>CLIENT IS LOCATED $client_offset_minutes MINUTES FROM UTC";
    echo "<br/>";

    echo "<br/>WHEN IT IS '$client_timestring' AT THE CLIENT, IT IS '$server_timestring' IN " . date_default_timezone_get();
}

// END OF PHP - USE HTML AND JS TO CREATE THE FORM
echo PHP_EOL; ?>

<form method="post">
<input name="date_O" id="dateTime_O" type="hidden" />
<input type="submit" value="CHECK CLIENT DATETIME" />
</form>

<!-- NOTE THIS WILL GIVE YOU THE VALUES AT PAGE-LOAD TIME, NOT AT SUBMIT TIME -->
<!-- MAN PAGE REF: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var dateObject = new Date();
document.getElementById("dateTime_O").value = dateObject.getTimezoneOffset();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I wanted to avoid javascript to hide the technique I used to my project. If PHP depends on JS at this task, then I can use JS directly without PHP.

Comment: PHP runs on the server.  It cannot see the client machine at all.  So if you want to get information from the client machines, you have to use a technology that runs on the client machine.  And that's why there is a requirement for JavaScript here.  You could also just ask the client to tell you their timezone.

Comment: Thank you. I've already done it. I tried to hide all the logic also that I used local Time zone. But it can not be! Now I did something like your thinking. Passed the timezone through ajax to php script.

Answer (score 1):

PHP, being server side, can only read what the client sends. It cannot tell the user timezone without being explicitly told by the user (or a user agent like the browser).

There are a couple ways to guess. You can look up the IP and guess timezone based on IP location by calling a location service (time expensive and can return incorrect results, I wouldn't recommend it).

You can also have your javascript make an ajax call to tell the server what the value for `Date().getTimezoneOffset()` is. Personally I would take this route.

Comment: I knew, & thought about these ways. But I was searching for such a way which I may not know. For a security issue I need to hide the script I used to my project. So wanted to do this task with server side coding which is not visible to the source view of my webpage. Thank you. :)

Comment: You can still hide significant logic by using AJAX: at that point, the javascript is only responsible for sending the data to your server, which then actually does all of the work on the data and returns the result, which the javascript is then only responsible for displaying. No proprietary logic is exposed this way if done properly.

Comment: Yes. I've just done it. But "I used local timezone" this logic gives Idea about my next steps. But nothing to do else it. Thank you so much.

Comment: "No proprietary logic is exposed this way" unless someone thinks to use View Source ;-)

Comment: The point is that if you have proprietary logic, you can move the proprietary elements to be server side (as in, php). "View Source" doesn't work on that (unless you've messed up your apache/etc config) ;) At which point your javascript is only to send additional data your server side logic needs (such as client timezone offset) and then display the results.